# How to use GCP KMS with Firebase and Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-kms

I need some advice on how to properly set up a solid security structure for my app.

### What my app does

The goal of this app is to provide a data aggregation service.
To do this, the user needs to provide login data for a variety of his accounts.

The user can then trigger a firebase cloud function which performs web scraping with the provided credentials, encrypts the result-data, and stores it to firestore.

### Current encryption

Currently, the encryption key is stored in a separate document in the firestore database.
The cloud function gets the key, performs de- and encryption, and stores the data as a cipher.

Now I know this is kind of pointless because if someone would hack my Google account, the data would still be readable for him.

### Problems

Besides this security flaw, I am facing some other problems.

As long as the described encryption only happens in a cloud function, this may be relatively secure because the cloud functions are isolated. My problem is, that there is no way to perform a database query from the client because:

1. there is no "onRead" cloud function, in which I would decrypt the data before sending it to the client
2. decrypting the data on the client would expose the encryption key to potential hackers (at least that's what I am thinking at the moment)

### Conclusion

I have decided to try GCP's KMS which seems to be the solution to all of these problems. However, I am overwhelmed by all these new terms and most of the resources I found seemed outdated.

Closest I came was this post: http://www.geero.net/2017/05/how-to-encrypt-a-google-firebase-realtime-database/ but since it's from 2017, it seems to be outdated (As far as I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59446316/10847224) answer)

So I am a bit lost on where to start, what to use, and how to manage responsibilities.

### Questions

1. Is it possible to create a secure client-sided decryption with KMS? If
   not, how should this get handled?
2. How do I implement KMS with firebase and firebase cloud functions? (Any pointing in the right
   direction would help)
3. Do you recommend using this package for the cloud function
   implementation:      https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/kms
4. Did you spot and other security flaws than those I mentioned?
5. Do you have any additional advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want "out of the box". If you're not pressed for time you can [request this feature](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) and wait.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't wait. Do you know of a workaround that you could recommend?

Comment: @Christian I’m currently in a similar situation, what approach did you at the end?

Comment: @magnetarneo I no longer use firebase or google-cloud. I am building a fullstack app and all the de/en-cryption happens on the server now.